# iOS: Why is the text written into this textfield within a custom TableViewCell not appearing to be readable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

so I have a tableview which is located in a view, within a view controller.

I then would want the tableview to have cells which have a text label on the left, and a text field to the right of this, so that a user can enter data in this text field.

I created a custom class tableviewcell, which looks as follows:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;


@end
```

and this, is the controller of the view within which the tableview and, thus, the cell, reside;

Header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SignUpViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *Table;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *SignUpTableNames;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;





@end
```

And the two methods to add my own cell type to this view/table:

```
- (TableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdent =@"Cell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdent forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //cell.textLabel.text =@"t";
    //NSString *s = [self.SignUpTableNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = (NSString *)[self.SignUpTableNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textField.placeholder = @"h";
    cell.textField.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    if (indexPath.row ==4)
    {
        cell.textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
    }

    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;

}
```

The cell.textLabel.text updates perfectly fine from the SignUpTableName NSMutableArray, but the cell.textField instances seem to be a problem. The text field is not visible, and I am not sure if it is there at all or not. If I tap where the text field should be, i do get a keyboard and can try to type into the field some data, but, i don't actually see the text on the screen.

What is wrong with this, why can't i see the text in the text field located within the custom cell?

Thanks so much, best regards,

chris

Just to clarify, i also set up the cell identifier to be "Cell" in th graphical user interface of xcode, as well as set up delegate and data source connections between the tableview and the view controller of the view, also via the graphical user interface of xcode.

Comment: Did you check the text field connection??

Comment: You mean whether the text field is connected as an IBOutlet to the Cell? Yes it is, see the first section of code in my original post

Comment: correction: the text field is visible if the cell is selected. if the cell is not selected, the text field, and the text in it, become not visible...

Answer (score 1):

Add this function in TableViewCell.m and make sure NSLog is printing ,if not copy the content in this function to any initializing function that you use

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self)
{

    _textField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, 150, 40)];
    [self addSubview:_textField];
    NSLog(@"init with style should be called");//this should be printed in log

}
return self;
}
```